# Why do I get Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments while invoking a method with varargs using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a method in a class as below

```
  class Sample{

    public void doSomething(String ... values) {

      //do something
    }

    public void doSomething(Integer value) {

    }

  }


//other methods
.
.
.
```

Now I get IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments below

```
Sample object = new Sample();
Method m = object.getClass().getMethod( "doSomething", String[].class );
String[] arr = {"v1","v2"};
m.invoke( object, arr ) // exception here
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wrap your `String` array in an `Object` array:

```
Sample object = new Sample();
Method m = object.getClass().getMethod("doSomething", String[].class);
String[] arr = {"v1", "v2"};
m.invoke(object, new Object[] {arr});
```

A varargs argument, even though it may be comprised of multiple values, is still considered to be one single argument. Since `Method.invoke()` expects an array of arguments, you need to wrap your single varargs argument into an arguments array.

Comment: Thanks and this is very helpful to me as well. But why we need to wrap this? I've tried even with an array of type object you still need to do this wrap, which I feel hard to understand.

Comment: @SamY Look at it like this: if your method accepts two `String` arguments, you need to send an array with two strings. If your methods accepts a `String` and a varargs `String...` argument, you need to send an array with a string (first argument) and an array of strings (second argument).

Answer (score 10):

`invoke` expects an array of arguments.

In your case, you have 1 argument, of type array, so you should send an array of size 1, with 1 member, which is the first (and only) argument.

Like so:

```
Sample object = new Sample();
Method m = object.getClass().getMethod( "doSomething", String[].class );
String[] arr = {"v1","v2"};
Object[] methodArgs = new Object[] {arr};
m.invoke( object, methodArgs ); // no exception here
```